# proof it if it is true statement or give counterexample if it is false.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

could you please help me with that 
proof it if it is true statement or give counterexample if it is false where $A,B$ and $C$ are sets.

a)If $A \subset C$ and $B \subset C$, then $(C − B) ∪ (C− A) = C − (A ∪ B)$.

b)If $ A \subset (B \cup C)$, then $ A \subset B $  or $  A \subset C$.

c) If  $ A \nsubseteq B \cap C$, then $ A \nsubseteq B  $ and $ A \nsubseteq C.$

for part a , I think it is true and we need to proof it for two both side that subset from each other.

for part b, I think, it is false statement by counterexample,
let $A=\{1,2,3\} , B=\{1,2,4\}$ , and $C=\{3,5\}$ ,so $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
so that $A ⊆ B ∪ C$ but $A \nsubseteq B  $ or $ A \nsubseteq C$.

for part C , I think, it is false statement by counterexample,
let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ , $B=\{1,2,3\}$, and  $C=\{4,5\}$, so $B\cap C= \emptyset$ 
so that $A \subseteq  B  $ and $ A \nsubseteq C$.

Comment: This looks like homework and should not be answered here. Also you may fix your notations; in (b) it should probably be: $A \subseteq (B \cup C)$

Comment: I do not want you to answer it ,I want you just to check my comment that is correct or not .Thanks

Comment: @gue, the OP showed effort toward solving their problem, so it seems reasonable (to me) to help them.  Also, I don't think parentheses are strictly required in part b; it would be analogous to saying $a=b+c$ must be written as $a=(b+c)$.  But conventions vary, and the parentheses certainly don't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counterexamples of parts b and c are fine.  Part a, however, is also false.  A counterexample along the lines of your others is $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3,4,5\}$, and $C=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Remark:  You might gain some additional understanding by going back over your counterexamples and seeing how much you can pare away from them and still have counterexamples.  In my answer above for part a, for example, it would suffice to let $A=C=\{1\}$ and $B=\emptyset$.

Comment: can be the empty set subset of {1} ?

Comment: @rianasd, yes, the empty set is a subset of *every* set.  In order for $\emptyset$ *not* to be a subset of a set $A$, it would have to have an element that is not an element of $A$.  But the empty set has no elements!